# How to create in "slide-in" animation without resizing the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have an animation where on page load an img object (and text object) slide in from outside the frame of the webpage. It works great, however, the only glaring issue is that at the very beginning of the load the webpage is resized for approx. half a second. This is because at that point in time, the img object is outside the frame so it resizes to compensate. This creates a really jerky effect on load. Is there anyway to treat it so that it just acts like it is outside the current bounds of the frame and only shows up on the webpage once part of it is in frame.

This is the simple CSS code for the animation as well as the CSS code for the image (it is a float so I can wrap text around it).

Also the current framework I am using is react, so if there is a React or JS solution, I would be happy to hear that as well.

```
@keyframes slideFromRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(800px) translateY(-80px);
    }
  
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);

.img--berk {
    float: right;
    width: 335px;
    height: 213px;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    border-radius: 9%;
    border: 4px solid var(--blue);
    animation: slideFromRight 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.35,-0.15, 0.63, 1.58);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your "App.js" css to "overflow: hidden;"?

Comment: @srWebDev Hmm, I guess I could try this. But for it to even work won't I need to define some height and width. I'm not sure how this would mess with the rest of the CSS, since it is 95% flexbox styling.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use a css animation at all. I would use Framer-Motion (https://www.npmjs.com/package/framer-motion). Create a variant with initial: {x: "100vw"}, animate: {x: "0vw"}.

Comment: @srWebDev Thankyou. I will give Framer Motion a shot! I tried recreating the animation with React-Spring but it ran into the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using react, I would use framer motion.

Install framer motion using `npm i --save framer-motion`   in the terminal.

```
    import {motion} from "framer-motion";
            
            const variants = {
            initial: { x: "100vw" },
            animate: { x: "0vw", 
            transition: { duration: 1.2 }
             }
            }
            
            export default function ImgComponent() {
return <motion.img class="img--berk" src="https://picsum.photos/200" initial="initial" animate="animate" variants={variants} />
        }
```

Not Forgetting to give your "App.js" component "overflow: hidden;"

Comment: Here are the docs: https://www.framer.com/docs/introduction/

Comment: Has this given you the desired outcome?

Comment: Thankyou for this. I installed framer-motion and copied your directions. Animations feel smoother on framer motion. But unfortunately, I am still running into the same issue. How exactly should I set overflow to hidden? I tried setting it to hidden in App.css. Also, I tried setting the current component I am working on which is the "aboutme" page (which I wrapped in a div which I set to hidden) but neither seemed to work.

Comment: Put this in your global css: * {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0;} html, body, #root {height: 100%;}  .App {position: relative; min-height: 100%;}. Then you can put "overflow: hidden;" on either the body or .App selector. It depends what you've already got going on elsewhere (try .App first). You could use "overflow-x: hidden;" if you like. It's also that the float could be a problem, but without seeing the rest of the code, I can't say why.